# ¿Es adecuado manejar controles en base a su nombre?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un conjunto de TextBox que se llaman por ejemplo: TB_Nombre, TB_Calle, TB_Telefono y TB_Email, los cuales serán alimentados desde una BD y los cuales los campos coinciden con el nombre, así que realice el siguiente código:

```
        List<string> d = new List<string> { "Nombre", "Calle", "Telefono", "Email"};
        DataRow registro = datos.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        foreach (string i in d){
                    TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("TB_" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
                    tb.Text = registro[i].ToString();                    
        }
```

sin duda hace el trabajo, pero ¿es adecuado trabajar los controles desde `Controls.Find`?

Comment: Qué tiene de malo que siguiendo la lógica de tu ciclo foreach tomes la referencia de tu control a partir de this.Controls["TB_"+i] as TextBox ???

Comment: Nota: el uso de los prefijos (notación húngara) en el nombre de las variables no es una práctica recomendada,yo en tu lugar usaría:  NombreTextBox, CalleTextBox, etc.... ver las Convenciones Generales de Nomenclatura para Net Framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Si te funciona correctamente, es adecuado, aunque yo probablemente usaría un diccionario:

```
var controlesDict= new Dictionary<string,TextBox>();
controlesDict.Add("Nombre", this.TB_Nombre);
controlesDict.Add("Calle", this.TB_Calle);
...
```

De esa manera,el acceso es muy sencillo e inmediato:

```
TextBox tb = controlesDict["Calle"];
controlesDict["Nombre"].Text="Pepe";
```